# Dialect class not found: org.hibernate.dialect.ExtendedSQLServerDialect

Tags: java, hibernate, query, modeling

I'm using a BI suite called Knowage (I hope there are some users here). When i try to build a Meta-Model i get the following error:

Error while initializing Qbe interface
*java.lang.RuntimeException: Impossible to build model structure*

Caused by *Dialect class not found: org.hibernate.dialect.ExtendedSQLServerDialect*

I really can't find this class anywhere so i'm wondering if someone can help me solving this issue. The only thing i figured out is that maybe i need a .jar file with this class to add in the lib folder of Knowage, but i really can't find anywhere a .jar file containing this class.
Thank in advance for the help!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19135346/org-hibernate-hibernateexception-dialect-class-not-found-org-hibernate-dialect

Comment: Sorry, but this is not solving the problem. Actually Maven is already used in the folders of the installation